# C - Strange Prototype Argument

Tags: c, prototype, void

What's going on in this function prototype? Obviously the void parameter with some sort of typecasting is confusing...

```
int *my_func(my_struct *m, void (*m_op)(my_struct *v, void arg));
```

Comment: Look up "function pointer" in your favorite C language book.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second argument to the function `my_func` is a pointer to a function that returns no value (`void`), but which takes two arguments, a `my_struct` pointer and ... and (an invalid) `void`.  The latter should probably be `void *arg`; you cannot have a variable or argument of type `void`.  As it stands, the code should not compile.

Answer (score 1):

This prototype declares a function, `my_func` that returns `int *`.  It takes two arguments, the first being of type `my_struct *` and the second of the strange type `void (*)(my_struct *, void)`. This means that the second argument is a pointer to a function that returns void and takes 2 arguments itself, a pointer to `my_struct` and `void` (I assume that was a typo and it takes a `void *`).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion - always try to split declarations into smaller ones - in that case code will be more readable. In this case you could re-write code as:

```
typedef struct {} my_struct;

typedef void (* m_op_function)(my_struct * v, void * arg);

int * my_func(my_struct * m, m_op_function f);
```

And as everybody said- it's almost 99,99% typo here regarding second parameter to m_op_function- it is possible `void*` - so that you can pass any pointer to it - be it `(char*), (int*), (my_struct*)`, or anything else. Simply just cast pointer.

Answer (score 0):

[This little article](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) explains how to parse C declarations in a spiral-like motion. Constructing is done in the reverse.